# Массив строк в массив обьектов JS

Tags: javascript

Как из массива строк:

```
var arr = ["{a:2}","{b:5}","{c:9}"];
```

сделать полноценный массив из объектов?

```
var arr = [{a:2},{b:5},{c:9}];
```

Пробовался вариант с разбивкой join(','), удалением кавычек регулярным выражением, но при сборке обратно в массив split(',') собирает опять строки, а нужны полноценные объекты в массиве. Спасибо!!

Comment: Может, вы лучше расскажете, откуда вы вообще берёте эту строку? А то парсить её в таком виде — идея не очень

Comment: Мой вопрос чисто теоретический - это мне ДЗ такое задали.

Comment: Чисто теоретически есть eval, но в реальном коде за его использование больно бьют

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключи не обёрнуты в двойные кавычки, что не JSON.
Нужно так:

```js
var arr = ['{"a":2}','{"b":5}','{"c":9}'];
console.info(arr.map(o => JSON.parse(o)));
```

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет возможно менять строку (

Comment: @MarinaDolganova, тогда нужен парсер. Структура ключей какова (могут ли быть пробелы, запрещённые символы, etc)? Остальные элементы как работают?